# converting number to string in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, itoa

I tried to find a lisp function to convert between numbers and strings and after a little googling I fond a function with the same name. when I entered `(itoa 1)` SLIME printed:

```
Undefined function ITOA called with arguments (1) .
```

How can I do the conversion?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From number to string:

```
(write-to-string 5)
"5"
```

you may transform a string to any numerical notation:

```
(write-to-string 341 :base 10)
"341"
```

From string to number:

```
(parse-integer "5")
5
```

with some trash

```
(parse-integer " 5 something not a number" :junk-allowed t)
5
```

Or use this:

```
(read-from-string "23 absd")
23
```

Comment: Do not use `read-from-string` on externally provided strings, or at least bind `*read-eval*` to false when you do.  Also of note for general number-parsing is the library `parse-number`.

Comment: Seems that `(write-to-string)` is depracated. Use `(number-to-string)` instead, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/String-Conversion.html.

Comment: @Student Looks like you assume this to be emacs lisp only.

Answer (score 20):

A heavyweight solution is to use FORMAT:

```
[2]> (format nil "~A" 1)
"1"
```

There is also [WRITE-TO-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_to_.htm):

```
[3]> (write-to-string 10)
"10"
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to the CLHS.  That helps make this answer more useful than it otherwise would be.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I believe (itoa #) is only a function in AutoLISP - the LISP variant embedded in AutoCAD drafting software. AutoLISP has far fewer functions than Common Lisp and sometimes identical functions with a different name or functions with the same name that operate differently.

That's probably why it didn't work for you. I use AutoLISP regularly and (itoa #) would do exactly what you want there.